# What does "These nights all roll together in a rush behind the mask" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Batman: The city's eating itself. Maybe it's beyond saving. But I have
> to try. Push myself. **These nights all roll  together in a rush behind
> the mask**. Sometimes in the morning, I have to force myself to remember
> everything that happened.

What does "These nights all roll together in a rush behind the mask" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to break it down. Not every sentence is a complete idiom with its own meaning.

**"The nights all roll together..."**
This is a variation of a common idiom. When days or nights are said to 'roll together' it means there feels like no separation between them. One begins where the other ends but there is nothing to mark it. Most people have a sense of what day of the week it is because the days are marked by routine and punctuated by sleep at night. Feeling like the days roll together can suggest a lack of these things.

**"...in a rush.."**
This suggests that the nights are passing so quickly this is what makes them blend together.

**"...behind the mask."**
Batman wears a mask. Everything he sees is from behind it.